# Inherited template function not being defined

Tags: c++, linked-list, member-functions

When I try to compile my code for main, my compiler keeps saying that mergeLists() is undefined. However, I expectedly defined it earlier (in the orderLinkedList class. In addition, I know I defined it as a member and I didn't put a calling object, but when I redefine it as a non-member it throws 
/--------------------------------------------
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
orderedLinkedList.h:204:6: note: candidate: template void mergeLists(orderedLinkedList&, orderedLinkedList&)
 void mergeLists(orderedLinkedList & list1, orderedLinkedList & list2) {
      ^
orderedLinkedList.h:204:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:43:31: note:   'unorderedLinkedList' is not derived from 'orderedLinkedList'
     mergeLists(list, otherList);
/------------------------------------------------
In addition to the other errors. What am I missing?

```
    template <class Type>
    void orderedLinkedList<Type>::mergeLists(orderedLinkedList<Type> & list1, orderedLinkedList<Type> & list2) {
        if(list2.first != NULL) {
            nodeType <Type> * current = list2.first;
            nodeType <Type> * trail = NULL;
            for(int cntr = 0; cntr <= list2.count; cntr++) {
                list1.insert(current->info);
                trail = current;
                current = current->link;
                delete trail;
            }
            list2.count = 0;
            list2.first = list2.last = NULL;
        }
    }








#ifndef H_orderedListType
#define H_orderedListType

#include "linkedList.h"

using namespace std; 

template <class Type>
class orderedLinkedList: public linkedListType<Type>
{
typedef linkedListType<Type> super;
using super::first;
using super::count;
using super::last;
public:
    bool search(const Type& searchItem) const; 
      //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the list, 
      //               otherwise the value false is returned.

    void insert(const Type& newItem);
      //Function to insert newItem in the list.
      //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem 
      //               is inserted at the proper place in the
      //               list, and count is incremented by 1.

    void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);
      //Function to insert newItem in the list.
      //Because the resulting list must be sorted, newItem is 
      //inserted at the proper in the list.
      //This function uses the function insert to insert newItem.
      //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
      //               inserted at the proper in the list,
      //               and count is incremented by 1.

    void insertLast(const Type& newItem);
      //Function to insert newItem in the list.
      //Because the resulting list must be sorted, newItem is 
      //inserted at the proper in the list.
      //This function uses the function insert to insert newItem.
      //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
      //               inserted at the proper in the list,
      //               and count is incremented by 1.

    void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);
      //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
      //Postcondition: If found, the node containing 
      //               deleteItem is deleted from the list;
      //               first points to the first node of the 
      //               new list, and count is decremented by 1.
      //               If deleteItem is not in the list, an
      //               appropriate message is printed.
    //void mergeLists(orderedLinkedList<Type> & list1, orderedLinkedList<Type> & list2);
};

/*******************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************/ 


template <class Type>
bool orderedLinkedList<Type>::search(const Type& searchItem) const
{
    bool found = false;
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

    current = first;  //start the search at the first node

    while (current != NULL && !found)
        if (current->info >= searchItem)
            found = true;
        else
            current = current->link;

    if (found)
       found = (current->info == searchItem); //test for equality

    return found;
}//end search


template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& newItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;  //pointer to create a node

    bool  found;

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node
    newNode->info = newItem;   //store newItem in the node
    newNode->link = NULL;      //set the link field of the node
                               //to nullptr

    if (first == NULL)  //Case 1
    {
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        current = first;
        found = false;

        while (current != NULL && !found) //search the list
           if (current->info >= newItem)
               found = true;
           else
           {
               trailCurrent = current;
               current = current->link;
           }

        if (current == first)      //Case 2
        {
            newNode->link = first;
            first = newNode;
            count++;
        }
        else                       //Case 3
        {
            trailCurrent->link = newNode;
            newNode->link = current;

            if (current == NULL)
                last = newNode;

            count++;
        }
    }//end else
}//end insert

template<class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
{
    insert(newItem);
}//end insertFirst

template<class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type& newItem)
{
    insert(newItem);
}//end insertLast

template<class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
    bool found;

    if (first == NULL) //Case 1
        cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list." << endl;
    else
    {
        current = first;
        found = false;

        while (current != NULL && !found)  //search the list
            if (current->info >= deleteItem)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->link;
            }

        if (current == NULL)   //Case 4
            cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the " 
                 << "list." << endl;
        else
            if (current->info == deleteItem) //the item to be 
                                   //deleted is in the list
            {
                if (first == current)       //Case 2
                {
                    first = first->link;

                    if (first == NULL)
                        last = NULL;

                    delete current;
                }
                else                         //Case 3
                {
                    trailCurrent->link = current->link;

                    if (current == last)
                        last = trailCurrent;

                    delete current;
                }
                count--;
            }
            else                            //Case 4
                cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the "
                     << "list." << endl;
    }
}//end deleteNode

template <class Type>
void mergeLists(orderedLinkedList<Type> & list1, orderedLinkedList<Type> & list2) {
    if(list2.first != NULL) {
        nodeType <Type> * current = list2.first;
        nodeType <Type> * trail = NULL;
        for(int cntr = 0; cntr <= list2.count; cntr++) {
            list1.insert(current->info);
            trail = current;
            current = current->link;
            delete trail;
        }
        list2.count = 0;
        list2.first = list2.last = NULL;
    }
}


#endif
```

My calling is such that mergeLists(list,otherlist); where list and other list are lists of type int

Comment: Can you please add the class declaration & and method definitions? it's hard to see what the problem is with partial data.

Comment: The first thing I shared was the method definition though.

Comment: *"When I try to compile my code for main..."* - which, inexplicably, you chose not to show. Don't you think it would be helpful to actually see the code that allegedly generates the error? Anyway, the error message suggests that you are passing an instance of `unorderedLinkedList` where `orderedLinkedList` is expected.

Comment: How are you calling the function?  Please add that as part of a [mcve]

Comment: I added how I called it...what do you mean by a minimal complete and verifiable example?